# Use SUM In Update Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, update

I am attempting to use `SUM()` in my `SET` statement for my `UPDATE`.  When I try this, I get an error of

> Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 234
>   An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

What should I alter in my `CTE` so that I can run this update?

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(Select EC, CN, CID, EntryDate
        FROM OPENQUERY(192.55.108.214,'select 
                              count(es.estimatenumber) As EC
                              ,cm.an CN
                              ,cm.am CID
                              ,es.entrydate EntryDate
                              from etalac es 
                              INNER JOIN bacalac cm
                              ON es.CID = cm.am
                              GROUP BY cm.an, cm.am, es.entrydate'))
UPDATE d2016
SET TotalNumber = SUM(EC)
FROM CTE cte
INNER JOIN datafor16 d2016
ON cte.CID = ed2016.CID
WHERE CAST(entrydate As Date) BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '01/22/2016';
```

Comment: You don't have a group by to use an aggregate but I think even with a proper aggregate it cannot but used in a set.

Comment: Really, rewrite that `WHERE CAST(entrydate As Date) BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '01/22/2016';` to `WHERE entrydate >= '20160101' AND entrydate < '20160123';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the aggregate in a subsequent cte, and update from there.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(Select EC, CN, CID, EntryDate
        FROM OPENQUERY(192.55.108.214,'select 
                              count(es.estimatenumber) As EC
                              ,cm.an CN
                              ,cm.am CID
                              ,es.entrydate EntryDate
                              from etalac es 
                              INNER JOIN bacalac cm
                              ON es.CID = cm.am
                              GROUP BY cm.an, cm.am, es.entrydate'))
, uCTE as (
  select cid, sumEC=sum(EC)
    from cte
    where CAST(entrydate As Date) BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '01/22/2016'
    group by cid
)
UPDATE d2016
  SET TotalNumber = sumEC
FROM uCTE cte
  INNER JOIN datafor16 d2016
    ON cte.CID = d2016.CID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is just

```
  ;WITH CTE AS 
  ( select cm.am CID 
         , count(es.estimatenumber) As EC
    from etalac es 
    INNER JOIN bacalac cm
           ON es.CID = cm.am 
    where CAST(es.entrydate As Date) BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '01/22/2016'
    GROUP BY cm.an   
  )
  UPDATE d2016
  SET TotalNumber = EC
  FROM cte
  INNER JOIN datafor16 d2016
          ON cte.CID = d2016.CID
```